# Equivalent of cv2.INTER_AREA in SkImage

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to reproduce a result from OpenCV using SkImage. In OpenCV we have:

```
img1 = cv2.resize(img, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

In SkImage, my best shot so far is:

```
img2 = skimage.transform.resize(img, (w, h))
```

However, I am still not able to get the same result as OpenCV. I read [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121acf959dca2480cc694ca016b81b442ceb) on cv2.INTER_AREA and [this article](https://medium.com/@wenrudong/what-is-opencvs-inter-area-actually-doing-282a626a09b3), but I am still unsure of how to reproduce this result in SkImage.

What is missing from the skimage implementation? A PIL.Image implementation could work too. Suggestions on how to diagnose the problem are appreciated.

Examples of the difference between img1 (OpenCV) and img2 (SkImage) are as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try downscale_local_mean at https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html?ref=driverlayer.com/web#skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean

Comment: What if it's upscaling?

Comment: INTER_AREA is bad for upscaling. According to opencv doc, during upscaling, INTER_AREA gives results similar to INTER_NEAREST

Comment: It does not make sense to upscale with blocks! Blocks are not relevant to upscaling. You need to interpolate or just use the nearest neighbor as @Micka suggested above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the width and height in `skimage` in wrong order. It should be reversed like below:

`img2 = skimage.transform.resize(img, (h, w))`

Then compare the result. Usually `skimage` produce better result compared to OpenCV.